# Maven plugins to build Maven plugins

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

My self-developed Maven plugins all contain the plugins

```
 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
    <artifactId>plexus-component-metadata</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.5</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>process-classes</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>generate-metadata</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.sonatype.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>sisu-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>generate-index</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>main-index</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Not only are they pretty old, I am not sure for what exactly I need them and to which version they should be updated.

Can someone shed light on this?

As requested, the full POM of one of the plugins:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>de.continentale.spu</groupId>
    <artifactId>conti-maven-plugin-mm</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

  <artifactId>conti-bom-maven-plugin</artifactId>

  <packaging>maven-plugin</packaging>

  <properties>
    <thirdPartyBomType>jar</thirdPartyBomType>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-plugin-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.aether</groupId>
      <artifactId>aether-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.aether</groupId>
      <artifactId>aether-impl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-aether-provider</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.aether</groupId>
      <artifactId>aether-connector-basic</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.aether</groupId>
      <artifactId>aether-transport-file</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.aether</groupId>
      <artifactId>aether-transport-http</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
      <artifactId>plexus-interactivity-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin-tools</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-plugin-annotations</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>de.continentale.spu</groupId>
      <artifactId>conti-maven-util</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
          <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
          <version>1.0.0</version>
          <configuration>
            <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
              <pluginExecutions>
                <pluginExecution>
                  <pluginExecutionFilter>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
                    <artifactId>plexus-component-metadata</artifactId>
                    <versionRange>[1.5.5,)</versionRange>
                    <goals>
                      <goal>generate-metadata</goal>
                    </goals>
                  </pluginExecutionFilter>
                  <action>
                    <ignore />
                  </action>
                </pluginExecution>
                <pluginExecution>
                  <pluginExecutionFilter>
                    <groupId>org.sonatype.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>sisu-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <versionRange>[1.4,)</versionRange>
                    <goals>
                      <goal>main-index</goal>
                    </goals>
                  </pluginExecutionFilter>
                  <action>
                    <ignore />
                  </action>
                </pluginExecution>
                <pluginExecution>
                  <pluginExecutionFilter>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-plugin-plugin</artifactId>
                    <versionRange>[3.3,)</versionRange>
                    <goals>
                      <goal>descriptor</goal>
                    </goals>
                  </pluginExecutionFilter>
                  <action>
                    <ignore />
                  </action>
                </pluginExecution>
              </pluginExecutions>
            </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
        <artifactId>plexus-component-metadata</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.5</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>process-classes</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>generate-metadata</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.sonatype.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>sisu-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>generate-index</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>main-index</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <reporting>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-plugin-plugin</artifactId>
        <reportSets>
          <reportSet>
            <reports>
              <report>report</report>
            </reports>
          </reportSet>
        </reportSets>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </reporting>
</project>
```

I use `@Mojo` as in the following example:

```java
@Mojo(name = "add-boms", requiresProject = true, requiresDependencyCollection = ResolutionScope.COMPILE)
public class AddBomsMojo extends AbstractMojo
```

Comment: Can you show the full pom file? plexus-component-metadata shouldn't be necessary for Maven 3+... sisu is a compatibility layer... Are you using `@Mojo` annotation in your plugin?

Comment: @khmarbaise Thanks for looking into it, I added a POM and the `@Mojo` definition. The versions of the dependencies are defined in the parent, so you cannot see them here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the mentioned plugins are indeed unnecessary and can be eliminated.